# How can I recover my unused space which I merged with Main APFS(Encrypted)?

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, partition

To increase the size of Main, I have merged the Main(Encrypted APFS) with another APFS partition. But now it is showing the previous size and I am not able to use the added space (See the size of Drive and Partition).

[image]

/dev/disk0 (internal):

```
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         121.3 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
2:                  Apple_HFS Rana                    12.7 GB    disk0s2
3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         12.7 GB    disk0s3
4:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         69.8 GB    disk0s4
```

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):

```
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +12.7 GB    disk1
                             Physical Store disk0s3
1:                APFS Volume Untitled                819.2 KB   disk1s1
```

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):

```
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +69.8 GB    disk2
                             Physical Store disk0s4
1:                APFS Volume Main                    62.9 GB    disk2s1
2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 43.4 MB    disk2s2
3:                APFS Volume Recovery                510.6 MB   disk2s3
4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk2s4
```

Answer (score 0):

For you, the best way is :

1. create a clone of your system on external bootable disk. Carbon copy Cloner do it.
2. boot with the clone.
3. erase completely the internal disk with apfs structure.
4. clone from external disk to internal.

Comment: Thanks Jean. I will try and let you know.

Comment: I have copied all my files and ready to load OS. I have no space to download the Mojave from Appstore but need to create a Starter disk. How to do that?

Comment: If you have done a clone with Carbon Copy Cloner (fully operational and free for one month during a trial period) you don't need download and reinstall Mac Os x. Con you, after boot on the clone, give me the result of `diskutil list ` and I'll give you the right command to erase the internal disk.